# How to disable comments at first column in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I am using WebStorm 9 IDE, but i have faced annoying issue with Line comments in LESS/HTML/CSS using "CTRL+/" hotkey, e.g.:

```
  .navbar-toggle {
//    margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
  }
```

As you can see it makes line comments at first column, i don't need that, i need this:

```
  .navbar-toggle {
    //margin: 13px 15px 13px 0;
  }
```

How can i do that for LESS/HTML/CSS?

For Javascript i can go in Settings -> Codestyle -> Javascript -> Wrapping and braces -> Uncheck "Comment at first column" and it works, but there's no such option for LESS/HTML/CSS. Need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible: such option has to exist on per language basis (it's not one-for-all option, unfortunately).

As I understand you have submitted new ticket already: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14255

LESS specific ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12549